# What might make a boolean modifier add unwanted edges?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'm working on a topological map animation.  It involves a map downloaded with GIS, a plane -> array modifier -> boolean modifier with world map.

The boolean modifier is occasionally creating strange edges in places it doesn't make sense.  It *mostly* works, but not all the way.  I'm trying to figure out what I can change to make the boolean modifier between a plane and a topographical map work more consistently.

Below I have pictures of two frames (11 & 12) that illustrate the issue.  The topo layers are moved slightly between the two, and the unexpected edges appear.  I've been looking at differences between these two frames and can't figure out what makes one boolean work and the other fail.

Link to file here (blend-exchange didn't work for some reason):  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vgJ-8wpymfBoCh9OWKpnlMZ3PKlXqZs2/view?usp=sharing

Right now my best guess is that there's something strange about the world map.  Maybe it's broken up into chunks or something.  It is probably not coincidence that some of the unwanted edges appear to follow an axis.

EDIT: I've narrowed down the issue some.  It has to do with pockets in the layers.  Like lakes, ponds, or other divets (you can see a tiny one in frame 12 too).  They seem to break the booleaned plane into multiple pieces.  Hopefully there's a modifier that can put them back together..

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These edges are a product of there being "holes" in the plane.  Blender can draw solid N-agons faces, without holes.  If there is a hole, the plane needs to be split into two in order to create the gap.  It's working exactly as would be expected.

[image]